# Semantic - CSS not working on mobile view

Tags: css, semantics

I'm using semantic-ui CSS making for responsive, but it is not working on mobile view, here is my class.

```
<div class="computer only twelve wide column mobile only UI container tablet only ui container"></div>
```

So there is something wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the text inside of the class attribute should go inside the <div> tag. O.o

Comment: Or it is actually used to style it but missing hyphens like: `computer-only twelve-wide-column mobile-only tablet-only ui-container`.

Comment: Maybe you guys should try looking at the library (http://semantic-ui.com/) before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

`UI` is capitalized after `mobile only`. The class names are case sensitive.

On top of that, I think you want to use the markup like this:

```
<div class="computer only twelve wide column">
    <!-- computer only stuff -->
</div>
<div class="mobile only ui container">
    <!-- mobile only stuff here -->
</div>
<div class="tablet only ui container">
    <!-- tablet only stuff here -->
</div>
```